# File descriptor returned from socket is larger than FD_SETSIZE

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp

I have a problem where the returned file descriptor would gradually increase to be a number larger than `FD_SETSIZE`.

My tcp server is continually shutdown which requires my client to close the socket and reconnect. The client will then attempt to reconnect to the server by calling `socket` to obtain a new file descriptor before calling `connect`.

However it appears that everytime I call `socket` the file descriptor returned is incremented and after a certain amount of time it becomes larger than `FD_SETSIZE`, which is a problem where I use `select` to monitor the socket.

Is it ok to reuse the first file descriptor returned from `socket` for the `connect` call even though the the socket was closed? Or is there other workarounds?

Reconnect code (looping until connected):

```
int s = getaddrinfo(hostname, port, &hints, &result);    
if (s != 0) { ... HANDLE ERROR ...}
...
struct addrinfo *rp;
int sfd;
for (rp = result; rp != NULL; rp -> ai_protocol)
{
    sfd = socket( rp->ai_family, rp->ai_sockettype, rp->ai_addrlen);
    if (sfd >= 0)
    {
       int res = connect(sfd, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen);
       if (res != -1)
       {
          _sockFd = sfd;
          _connected = true;
          break;   
       }
       else
       {
          close (sfd);
          break; 
       }
    } 
}
if (result != NULL)
{
    free(result);
}
```

Read Message code:

```
if (_connected)
{
   ...
   retval = select(n, &rec, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
   if (retval == -1) 
   {
      ...
      _connected = false;
      close(_sockFd);      
   }
   else if (retval)
   {
      if (FD_ISSET(_sockFD, &rec) == 0)
      {
         ....
         return;
      }

      int count = read(...)

      if (count)
      {
         ....
         return;
      }
      else
      {
         ....
         _connected = false;
         close(_sockFd);
      } 
   }
}
```

Comment: Post the relevant code.  You are doing something wrong.  If you are really closing the socket fd then you should get the same one on the subsequent open.  And you shouldn't get a returned FD larger than FD_SETSIZE unless you explicitly set your process to increase the default number of FDs per process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not closing the socket if the connect fails. So it remains open, occupying an FD, so next time you call socket() you get a new FD. You're also not breaking out of your loop when connect() succeeds, which is another leak. You're also not checking the result of read() for -1.

Comment: The missed break if is connected is a typo (sorry I had to manually type across code).  I will try to add the close after it fails to connect.

Comment: And yes the close after it fails to connect fixes it! Cheers.